How can I prevent Matplotlib from autoscaling images to the same size in subplots?
I’m trying to display three images of different sizes side-by-side using Matplotlib. I want each subplot to maintain the original size of the images without auto scaling them to be the same size.

img_512 = down_sample(1024, 512, img)

img_512_upsample = up_sample(512, 1024, img_512)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(15,10))

ax[0].imshow(img, cmap='gray', aspect='equal', extent=[0, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 0])
ax[0].set_title(f"Original Image")
ax[0].axis('on')

ax[1].imshow(img_512, cmap='gray', aspect='equal', extent=[0, img_512.shape[1], img_512.shape[0], 0])
ax[1].set_title(f"Down Sample to 512x512")
ax[1].axis('on')


ax[2].imshow(img_512_upsample, cmap='gray', aspect='equal', extent=[0, img_512_upsample.shape[1], img_512_upsample.shape[0], 0])
ax[2].set_title(f"Up Sample to 1024x1024")
ax[2].axis('on')

plt.autoscale(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

Image of my result
I tried turning off auto scaling, setting aspect to equal and tried setting the extent to the sizes of the images.

what is down_sample and up_sample? remember to always include all relevant code in your question

If you want the subplots the same size, use sharex/sharey in the call to subplots:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((1024, 1024))
img_512 = np.zeros((512, 512))
img_512_upsample = np.zeros((1024, 1024))

fig, ax_arr = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(15,10), sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax_arr[0].imshow(img, cmap='gray', aspect='equal', extent=[0, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 0])
ax_arr[0].set_title(f"Original Image")

ax_arr[1].imshow(img_512, cmap='gray', aspect='equal', extent=[0, img_512.shape[1], img_512.shape[0], 0])
ax_arr[1].set_title(f"Down Sample to 512x512")

ax_arr[2].imshow(img_512_upsample, cmap='gray', aspect='equal', extent=[0, img_512_upsample.shape[1], img_512_upsample.shape[0], 0])
ax_arr[2].set_title(f"Up Sample to 1024x1024")

plt.show()


If instead you want the middle subplot half the height and width, use width_ratios in the call to subplots:
fig, ax_arr = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(15,10), width_ratios=[2, 1, 2])


You can align the subplots by their top or bottom edge using the anchor property - "N" for north or "S" for south:
for ax in ax_arr:
    ax.set_anchor("N")



You can adjust the middle Axes position using set_position:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((1024, 1024))
img_512 = np.zeros((512, 512))
img_512_upsample = np.zeros((1024, 1024))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(15,10))

ax[0].imshow(img, cmap='gray', aspect='equal', extent=[0, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 0])
ax[0].set_title(f"Original Image")

ax[1].imshow(img_512, cmap='gray', aspect='equal', extent=[0, img_512.shape[1], img_512.shape[0], 0])
ax[1].set_title(f"Down Sample to 512x512")

ax[2].imshow(img_512_upsample, cmap='gray', aspect='equal', extent=[0, img_512_upsample.shape[1], img_512_upsample.shape[0], 0])
ax[2].set_title(f"Up Sample to 1024x1024")

pos = ax[1].get_position()
ax[1].set_position([pos.x0 + pos.width/4, pos.y0, pos.width/2, pos.height/2])

plt.show()


If you want to apply a tight layout, make sure to do so before setting the position:
fig.tight_layout()
pos = ax[1].get_position()
ax[1].set_position([pos.x0 + pos.width/4, pos.y0, pos.width/2, pos.height/2])


(constrained layout works fine when set in plt.subplots)
In the general case of more subplots or when you want to control the space between subplots this manual method quickly becomes cumbersome. In this case you may want to use the axes_grid1 toolkit.
